StyleSheet in MMA 14.1
This works with MMA 14.0:
c:\users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets\calibri.nb
This doesn't work with MMA 14.1, why? :
c:\users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Wolfram\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets\calibri.nb

What is calibri.nb? I don't find that stylesheet in v14.0, but it sounds like a font name.

Have you tried following these instructions?
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UpgradingFromMathematicaToWolfram.html#233490758

Might also try this utility function:
https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MigrateSettingsToWolframApp/
